# Краш CoreFoundation: CFArrayApplyFunction

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, swift3

Крашлитикс отловил краши, не знаю пока как в них разбираться, помогите пожалуйста. Что-то, очевидно, связанное с покупками.

1. Первый crash. 15 строка апделегата, но там `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate`:

   > #0 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
   >   EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x003a746e7b8c7868
   >
   > 0    libobjc.A.dylib  objc_msgSend + 28
   >
   > 1    StoreKit         __NotifyObserverAboutChanges + 84
   >
   > 2    CoreFoundation   CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
   >
   > 3   StoreKit      -[SKPaymentQueue
   >   _notifyObserversAboutChanges:sendUpdatedDownloads:] + 148
   >
   > 15  UIKit        UIApplicationMain + 208
   >
   > 16   Back      AppDelegate.swift line 15main
   >
   > 17   libdispatch.dylib
   >   (Missing)
2. Второй crash, тоже 15 строка:

   > #0     Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
   >   EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000b00200450
   >
   > 0    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 16
   >
   > 1    StoreKit            __34-[SKProductsRequest _handleReply:]_block_invoke + 52
   >
   > 2   libdispatch.dylib    _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
   >
   > 10  UIKit        UIApplicationMain + 208
   >
   > 11   Back       AppDelegate.swift line 15 main
   >
   > 12   libdispatch.dylib
   >   (Missing)
3. Третьий crash:

   > #0    Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
   >   EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000010
   >
   > 0    libobjc.A.dylib   objc_msgSend + 16
   >
   > 4    StoreKit       -[SKPaymentQueue addPayment:] + 316
   >
   > 5    Back       ViewController.swift line 151
   >                   ViewController.buyProduct() -> ()
   >
   > 6    Back       ViewController.swift line 0
   >       specialized ViewController.buyAllButtonTapped(UIButton) -> ()
   >
   > 7    Back    ViewController.swift line 0
   >   @objc ViewController.buyAllButtonTapped(UIButton) -> ()
   >
   > 8  UIKit -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
   >
   > 23  UIKit     UIApplicationMain + 208
   >
   > 24   Back    AppDelegate.swift line 15 main
   >
   > 25   libdispatch.dylib
   >   (Missing)

Код покупок:

```
// Проверка на возможность покупки
if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
    print("Покупки доступны")
    let productID: Set<String> = ["Back.BuyAllThings"]
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
} 
else {
    print("Покупки не доступны")
}
// Добавляем платеж в очередь платежей
func buyProduct() {
    print("buy " + productToPurchase.productIdentifier)        
    let pay = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(pay)
}      // 151 LINE

func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("Product request phase")

    let myProduct = response.products

    for product in myProduct {
        print("Товар добавлен")
        print("Идентификатор продукта: \(product.productIdentifier)")
        print("\(product.localizedTitle)")
        print("\(product.localizedDescription)")

        listOfProducts.append(product)
    }
}
//НАЖАТИЕ НА КНОПКУ ПОКУПКИ 
func buyAllButtonTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
print("КУПИЛ ВСЕ ПОКУПКИ")

for product in listOfProducts {
    let productID = product.productIdentifier
    if productID == "ru.artursk.Back.BuyAllThings" {
        productToPurchase = product

        buyProduct()
        break        
    }
}

/ Обновляет сведения о транзакции
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        print("Ошибка: \(transaction.error)")

        switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased:

                print("Оплата прошла успешно")
                print(productToPurchase.productIdentifier)

                let prodID = productToPurchase.productIdentifier
                switch prodID {

                    case "Back.BuyAllThings":
                        print("Покупаем All Things")
                        addAll() //  АКТИВИРУЕМ КУПЛЕННОЕ
                        break

                    default:
                        break
                }
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                break

            case .failed:
                print("Ошибка транзакции")
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            default:
                print("paymentQuene - default case")
            break
        }
    }
}

func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    print("удаляем транзакцию из очереди")
}
```

Полный стэк на первый сбой
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите весь крэш лог - у вас шаги с 3 по 15 пропущены в первом и так далее. и поскольку у вас в крэшах есть информация о том, какая именно строка привела а крешу (например `4 StoreKit -[SKPaymentQueue addPayment:] + 316` - строка с номером 316), было бы неплохо, если бы вы в коде где то дали указание, типа вот строка 316

Comment: Максим, там два файла, в которых краши. Спасибо  https://yadi.sk/d/LPDoAg0Vwy8yK

Comment: Идея про add() -  неправильная, которую я предлагал. Но то что вижу - нужно также делать `remove(self)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но то что вижу - нужно также делать remove(self) перед выходом с контроллера. Скажи, это единственный контроллер в приложении или есть ещё? Если есть ещё, то краш вопсроизведётся, если зайти на контроллер раз, купить что-то, потом выйти с него, зайти снова и ещё раз купить.
Суть в том, что контроллер добавляется в очередь (причём не один раз, а при каждой покупке, что тоже похоже на косяк), но не убирается из неё. Такое добавление на самом деле вызоват также продёрнивание обсёрверу всех предыдущих транзакций, которые не были finished. Поэтому тут нужно хорошо разобраться как именно работает `StoreKit` и как правильно взаимодействовать с `SKPaymentQueue`.

Вообще не рекомендую обсёрвить пеймент кью вью контроллером - тут лучше иметь синглтон, который посылает нотификации о событиях. Попробуй заюзать какие-нибудь готовые решения, вроде есть остаточно много достойных

Comment: Это первый контроллер, из которого попадаешь на др при покупке доступа к ним. Я пока только изучаю программирование, поэтому во многом еще не разобрался. Может подскажешь какие-то решения... Спасибо

Comment: Явных проблем в коде не вижу, и если контроллер всего один - кажется, что приложение должно как минимум не крашиться. Попробуй не делать `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)` по нажатию на кнопку (только payment по нажатию), а делать это на `viewWillAppear`, соответственно на `viewDidDisappear` `SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)`. А крашится апп по нажатию на restore?

Comment: Отследить именно что на restore не довелось, но думаю что нет, тк приложению месяц в сторе и сбою по несколько раз в неделю

Comment: А есть стек певого краша между 3 и 15?

Comment: Добавил в вопрос скрин